# Почему attempt возвращает false

Tags: php, laravel

Столкнулся ошибкой при аутентификации: при попытке пройти её,  метод `Auth::attempt` возвращает `false`, хотя телефон и пароль правильный.

Я думаю дело в том, что в моей таблице `password` называется, как `passhash`.

Таблица - User

[image: Таблица - User]

Класс регистрации:

```
protected function create(Request $data) {
    if (User::where('phone', '=', $data['phone'])->exists()) {
        return response()->json(array('status' => 'error', 'msg'=>'The phone number already exists'), 422);
    } else {
        $user_id = User::create([
            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],  
            'surname' => $data['surname'],
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
            'passhash' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
        return response()->json(array('status' => 'created', 'id' => $user_id['id']), 201);
    }
}
```

Класс аутентификации

```
public function login(Request $request) {

    $credentials = [
        'phone' => $request['phone'],
        'password' => $request['password'],
    ];

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json(array('token' => 'Вы успешно авторизировались!'), 200);
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            'error' => 'Incorrect phone or password',
        ], 404);
    }
}
```

Меня так же беспокоит правильно ли, что я при регистрации пароль хеширую `bcrypt` или лучше использовать `Hash::make` и как правильно указывать пароль аутентификации?

Answer (score 4):

Аутентификация в laravel по умолчанию работает с колонкой `password`, а точнее с атрибутом модели User `$password`.

У вас есть 2 варианта:

1) Переименовать колонку `passhash` в `password`.

2) Переопределить метод `getAuthPassword()` в модели User:

```
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->passhash;
}
```

С созданием пользователя все в порядке, `Hash::make()` по умолчанию использует алгоритм `bcrypt`, поэтому `Hash::make()` и `bcrypt()` фактически делают одно и то же.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, исправил то, что вы порекомендовали и всё равно показывает False, а при аутентификации нужно пароль хешировать или нет ?